# running eth-net-intelligence-api throws "[eth] =✘= Web3 connection attempt #0 failed"

Tags: go-ethereum, ethstats

I am trying to run eth-netstart in my machine.

I run geth using this command line:

```
geth --datadir innofactory1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30312 --rpc --ws --wsorigins "*" --rpccorsdomain '"*"' --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8502 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://20c47b4a7bd6d8383f87c1c988e601c7aa27ba7177b25d57e00794d1917c0c992dc37b93dfdf54741633179fd9a96a34fc2687d606ad48e2015ef2d958f3f0fb@10.2.1.124:30310' --networkid 1515 --gasprice '0' --unlock '0x40ee4953da28c4db0f15d671cefc29724ce2b87a' --password innofactory1/password.txt --mine
```

and I configure the app.json like this:

```
[
  {
    "name"              : "node-app",
    "script"            : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"   : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "merge_logs"        : false,
    "watch"             : false,
    "max_restarts"      : 10,
    "exec_interpreter"  : "node",
    "exec_mode"         : "fork_mode",
    "env":
    {
      "NODE_ENV"        : "production",
      "RPC_HOST"        : "localhost",
      "RPC_PORT"        : "8502",
      "LISTENING_PORT"  : "30312",
      "INSTANCE_NAME"   : "",
      "CONTACT_DETAILS" : "",
      "WS_SERVER"       : "http://localhost:3000",
      "WS_SECRET"       : "secret",
      "VERBOSITY"       : 2
    }
  }
]
```

but when I run :

```
npm start app.json
```

I got this error: 
**[eth] =✘= Web3 connection attempt #0 failed**

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by specifying **INSTANCE_NAME** and **CONTACT_DETAILS**